# How does image_dataset_from_directory() order the predictions of a numerical class name?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Does image_dataset_from_directory() order the class names as specified by me i.e., [0,10,5] or is it sorted alphanumerically?

I am asking because when I use the model to make predictions I want to be sure that the order I set is followed or not.

```
train_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory=TRAIN_DIR,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="categorical",
    class_names=["0", "10", "5"],
    image_size=SIZE,
    seed=SEED,
    subset=None,
    interpolation="bilinear",
    follow_links=False,
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If will follow the order specified in `class_names` argument.

If you don't specify anything the order will be according to alphanumeric sorting.

The exact statement from Tensorflow Documentation for argument `class_names`:

> Only valid if "labels" is "inferred". This is the explict list of
> class names (must match names of subdirectories). Used to control the
> order of the classes (otherwise alphanumerical order is used).

See the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset_from_directory#arguments)